# VBA coding for Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

Does anyone know if the vba code that is produced in Outlook 2016 is backwards compatible with 2010. I use 2007 at home & 2010 at work. I wrote a program in 07 and needed a lot of head scratching to get it working in 2010. I wish thinking of updating home to 2016. My question is then I would be '16 at home & '10 in the office - would this create the same problem as I have now?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what Outlook Object Model features you're using in your VBA. Each Outlook version introduces new objects and/or functions that are not exist in previous versions. So, always see "Applies To" in MSDN articles to make your VBA work for Outlook 2010-2016.